# validation control

Tags: asp.net

I've a Regular expression validation to accept aphabets only. But currently its not accepting any user input data...

Comment: you should provide some code.. or error.. at least something..
cany help you if you dont help us

Answer (score 1):

Use this RE Control :

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="please input alphabets." ControlToValidate="txtInput" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]+$" Height="19px" Width="165px"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... i tried other expressions.. it wasn't working